# Save PHP Session data across different directories

Tags: mysql, session

I'm trying to save PHP session data across directories. This code does not work for me and I need it to redirect to a different directory.
index.html:

```
<html>
 <form action='login.php' method='get'>
  Username: <input type='text' name='user' /><br>
  Password: <input type='password' name='pass' /><br>
  <input type='submit' />
 </form>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root' ,'a91c95n00', 'db_games2');
$sql = "SELECT username FROM userdata WHERE username='$user'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0){
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
 header('location:games.php');
}elseif ($count == 1){
 header ('location:error.html');
}
?>
```

games.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 session_save_path('/var/www/html/1/');
 session_save_path('/var/www/html/2/');
?>
<html>
 <a href='http://76.29.204.37/1'>Product 1</a><br>
 <a href='http://76.29.204.37/2'>Product 2</a>
</html>
```

/1/index.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  header ('location:error.html');
 }elseif (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  header('location:success.php');
 }
?>
```

Every time I go to the product 1 directory, it goes to error.html..
When a session is set, it is supposed to go to success.php. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: PHP sessions are not specific to a directory in the server. You do not have to take care to save them, especially you do not need to call `session_save_path()` manually. This might actually be the cause of the issue here. Sessions last until they are destroyed manually or until the http server restarts. They can be used in all requests regardless of the directory.

Comment: OK, so let me get this straight: the server saves the session data in any directory or subdirectory? If that's the case, then why isn't the server saving the session data? As you can see in my code, I haven't manually destroyed the session at all.

Comment: Correct, the server saves the session data in the default location configured. You are not really interested in that location, it is some internal location. I cannot say why this currently does not work for you, sorry. But you definitely do not have to take care to manually save the session data.